# Get components on the content delivery side using the java content delivery api and check component templates used for it

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, java, api

I am working on tridion content delivery java api.

I would like to know which java classes are invoked on publishing a component from tridion.

My requirement is to check the component published, check the component template used by it, and if it is specfic component template, I would place it in some incoming folder.

Found one configuration in cd-deployer_conf.xml:

```
<Module Type="ComponentDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy" />
```

Created one class, overriding this class, overrided its methods, but it did not get invoked.

Anyone having any information in this regard please let me know.

Comment: Can you edit your tags for this question properly or explain which version of Tridion you are using?

Comment: We are using Tridion 2013.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/in-tridion-content-delivery-api-java-is-it-possible-to-get-package-zip-file-whi

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use the component template used to publish one component, probably you have to create your own **ComponentPresentationDeploy** instead of the **ComponentDeploy**.

You can extend the **ComponentPresentationDeploy** with a custom module, adding the functionality as you need as stated in [sdllivecontent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US&docid=concept_9C539892142D48CC99AE0B89DE8780B1&query=custom%20deployer#docid=concept_3BB06135CEAE45FEA437937ECFC54864&filename=ModifyingTheBehaviorOfAnExistingModule.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_3BB06135CEAE45FEA437937ECFC54864) (requires login)

Answer (score 1):

As you have guessed - Tridion uses the java classes that are specified in its configuration files. So if you inherit from ComponentDeploy, simply replacing the class name in the configuration file, ensuring your class is on the classpath, and restarting everything should be enough to get your code to execute.

Having said that, ComponentDeploy may not be the correct hook for what you are trying to do. In old versions of Tridion, custom deployers were common (although do take note of Raul's point - there may be other Deploy classes you'd need to customise). Current versions of Tridion also allow for customised storage classes. If you search on this site for "Storage Extension" you will find enough examples.